# Primeng ConfirmDialog is not closed after clicking Yes, No or Close(X)

Tags: angular

Using PrimeNg ConfirmDialog(p-confirmDialog) in P-table to delete record. The confirm dialog is not closing after clicking Yes/No/close(X).

following is the method which i am calling clicking delete

```
confirm(id) {
    console.log("User Id---  "+id);
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
    message: 'Do you want to delete this record?',
    header: 'Delete Confirmation',
    icon: 'pi pi-info-circle', 
    accept: () => {
        this.deleteUser.emit(id);
    },
    reject: () => {

     }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`p-confirmDialog` must be used by the `ConfirmationService` and an example of its use is like this:

```
import { ConfirmationService } from 'primeng/components/common/api';

 export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private confirmationService: ConfirmationService) { }

  canDelete() {
    return Observable.create((observer: Observer<boolean>) => {
      this.confirmationService.confirm({
        message: 'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to leave this page?',
        accept: () => {
          observer.next(true);
          observer.complete();
        },
        reject: () => {
          observer.next(false);
          observer.complete();
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

And in the view template you have to provide the `confirmDialog` like this:

```
<p-confirmDialog header="Warning" icon="fa fa-question-circle">
```

Hope it helps!
Make sure to provide some code next time, otherwise your post will be then downrated.